# InfluxDB fill(linear) only intervals lesser than x minutes

Tags: time-series, influxdb, influxdb-2

I need to fill in missing data in an InfluxDB query grouped by 10 seconds, using linear interpolation (`fill(linear)`), but only if the gap between data points is less than 10 minutes. For any gaps longer than that, I want the query to either return no data or return the data with NULL values for the missing points, instead of filling them in. How can I achieve this?"

For InfluxDB 1.6 and influxDB 2